# Order of rules - Is it a real necessity?

Tags: gitignore

Do you have **concrete** examples where the order of the rules in a `gitignore` is important?

Comment: Are you running into particular problems with a gitignore where you think this may be due to the order of rules?

Comment: Where did you get the impression that the rule order was important? I do not see any reference that this is the case from [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: I am working on a tool to produce minimalistic `gitignore` files. I have never experienced the necessity to respect an order of analysis.